# Successfully login with Twitter using social framework but not able to fatch user profile in ios8

Tags: iphone, ios7, twitter

Following code I have implemented to login with Twitter in ios 8. With the help of this code I am able to successfully login after writing username and password in device's Setting's twitter app. But I am not able to fetch user's profile from Twitter. I am only able to fetch email address.(username for twitter). Following is my code.

In .h file I import frameworks like

```
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>
#import <Accounts/AccountsDefines.h>
#import <Social/Social.h>
```

In .m file I write following code

```
- (IBAction)btnLoginWithTwiitterClicked:(id)sender {

    //[AppCommon showProgressHUD:NSLocalizedString(@"ProgressHUD_LoadingData", @"'Loading Data','Laden van Gegevens','Daten werden geladen' -General message")];
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) // check Twitter is configured in Settings or not
    {
        self.accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init]; // you have to retain ACAccountStore

        ACAccountType *twitterAcc = [self.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

        [self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterAcc options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
         {
             if (granted)
             {
                 NSArray *accountsArray = [self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:twitterAcc];
                 //[AppCommon hideProgressHUD];
                 NSDictionary *twitterAccount = [[self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:twitterAcc] lastObject];
                 NSLog(@"Twitter UserName: %@", [twitterAccount valueForKey:@"username"]);
             }
             else
             {
                 if (error == nil) {
                     //[AppCommon hideProgressHUD];
                     NSLog(@"User Has disabled your app from settings...");
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     //[AppCommon hideProgressHUD];
                     NSLog(@"Error in Login: %@", error);
                 }
             }
         }];
    }
    else
    {
        //[AppCommon hideProgressHUD];
        NSLog(@"Not Configured in Settings......"); // show user an alert view that Twitter is not configured in settings.
    }
}
```

Frinds further I have no idea how to fetch user's other detail.

Any help would be appriciable

Thanx in advance.

Comment: refere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334731/ios-how-to-get-twitter-account-access/18779730#18779730

Comment: @preetam I implemented your code but I got error. "The response status code is 404".

Answer (score 1):

I am using same code
just try to NSLog or Po `twitterAccount`. You will see whole dictionary